# Logic App with trigger when email sent to Office 365 Group/Teams channel

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, office-365-groups, logic-app

I am wondering if there is a trigger in Logic Apps to tap into incoming emails of a Teams channel that was created. The channel has an email address associated to it.

However, I can't find any trigger related to this. Is this even possible using the Logic App?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a newly released **Office 365 Groups Mail Connector (Preview)** which has a trigger **When a new email arrives to a group**.

Check below official documentation for more information on this connector:

[Office 365 Groups Mail (Preview)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365GroupsMail)

Comment: Thank you. Let me test this.

Comment: It got all setup correctly but doesn't seem to read any incoming emails. trigger is fine but no emails read.

Comment: Can you please add any screenshot or something of the setup and configuration you did for this? It will be helpful to find the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

The connector reference  by Ganesh is for the actual shared mailbox for the group itself, not the email addresses you can use to send items to a Teams channel.